# Initializing structure with variable length array in C

Tags: c, struct, variable-length-array

Does anyone know if there is a way to initialize a structure containing a variable length array without initializing the array first in a separate variable (and without using malloc)?

My structure looks like this:

```
struct my_struct {
    int *values;
    int size;
}
```

For now in my code I have that:

```
void my_function (int size) {
    int values[size];
    struct my_struct mystr = {
        .values = values,
        .size = size
    };
    ...
}
```

(Array is initialized first, then the structure. This is working but it looks awkward to declare a separate variable for the array.)

This would probably work as well:

```
void my_function (int size) {
    struct my_struct mystr = { 
        .values = calloc (size, sizeof (int)),
        .size = size
    };
    ...
}
```

(but I do not want to use mallocs)

But what I would like to write is something like:

```
void my_function (int size) {
    struct my_struct mystr = { 
        .values = (int[size]){},
        .size = size
    };
    ...
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to have an array without allocating space for it?

Comment: I know I have to allocate space for the array, but I would like to do so without using an intermediate variable such as `int values[size];`.

Comment: What is wrong with ` .values = calloc (size, sizeof (int)),`?

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation is slower and, if you are not careful, can lead to memory leaks. Hence I try to avoid this unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: So initialize the `.values` with NULL and put the real value when you allocate the memory

Comment: "*... initialize a structure containing a variable length array*" `int * values;` is a pointer to `int` and not an array, not even a VLA.

Comment: "Dynamic memory allocation is slower..." If this was your rationale for asking this question, it is invalid. Technically speaking, the C standard has no such requirement; VLAs may be implemented internally using `malloc` to save precious *stack space*. Realistically speaking, it should make no significant difference so long as you don't complicate the cache locality. Stop using a pointer to refer to a different chunk of memory, for a start. Use a flexible array member, instead.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that you cannot use an array from your stack if you want to return your structure.

```
int values[size];
struct my_struct mystr = {
    .values = values,
    .size = size
};
return mystr;
```

This is not going to work since the lifetime of `values` ends when you return. The same applies if you try to store `mystr` in a value pointed by a parameter of your function.

Obviously you're not doing that, however I think it's worth to mention anyway.

---

Answer to your question: it depends on the situation.

Can you be sure that `size` is small? Or else your stack is going to overflow in `int values[size]`. Is it small and predictable? Stick with your first solution. If it can be large or dependent on user-input, definitely use `malloc`.

Are you in some way returning or retaining a persistent pointer to your structure or values? Use `malloc` (see my first remark).

Alternatively, you can also use the [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) but then you would have to `malloc` the entire `mystr` anyway.

---

One more thing, you wrote:

> (Array is initialized first, then the structure. This is working but
>   it looks awkward to declare a separate variable for the array.)

I'm not sure what you mean, but the `int *` is only `sizeof(intptr_t)`, irregardless of the size of the array. So you're not allocating twice the memory for 1 array, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: `sizeof (int *)` is not necessarily equal to `sizeof (intptr_t)`. I think you missed the point; OP isn't concerned about performance or memory use in this question. He/she wants to be more expressive... Those two concepts run orthogonally.

Answer (score -1):

Initializer are unnamed objects initialized by the initializer list. Outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration. So it is possible to use the address of such an object. With a little help from variadic macros you can try →

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 struct test {
   int count;
   int *values;
 } test[] = {
 #define init(...) { .count=sizeof( (int[]) {__VA_ARGS__} )/sizeof(int), .values=(int *)&(int []){__VA_ARGS__} }
              init(0,1,2,3,4),
              init(2,4,6,8),
              init(1,3),
              init(42)
            };
 #define test_size ((int) (sizeof test/sizeof *test))

 int main(void)
 {
   for(int array=0; array<test_size; ++array) {
     printf("array %d (%d) : [ ", array+1, test[array].count);
     for(int i=0; i<test[array].count; ++i)
       printf("%d ", test[array].values[i]);
     puts("]");
   }
   return 0;
 }
```